oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver (class file version 54.0), This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
lately, I have been trying to connect my Data bricks with the Oracle Cloud through using the wallet connection, here are several things I have tried:

Downgrading from ojdbc11 to ojdbc8, as I saw on Oracle JDBC Driver, there are several different editions of the same ojdbc8.jar (and Java SE 8 is expected to work with this ojdbc8 as well), and I have tried them all, none of them worked.
Configure the extra class path and the wallet connection zip files to the Spark Session, this is the code that I have used

%python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('SparkContent') \
    .config('spark.driver.memory', '15g') \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', "dbfs:/FileStore/jars/1fb67c34_0526_452f_9bf5_da85c99904de-ojdbc8.jar") \
    .config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/1fb67c34_0526_452f_9bf5_da85c99904de-ojdbc8.jar') \
    .config('spark.net.wallet_location', 'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/triethoangminh555@gmail.com/Wallet_PRFFIGRTZ8WW08IK.zip') \
    .getOrCreate()


Configure the options in the write method for spark, this is the code that I have used

connection_url  = f'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.af-johannesburg-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=ge1e779a6634c11_prffigrtz8ww08ik_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))'
    username = ''
    password = ''
    table_name = ''
    driver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
    df.write \
        .format('jdbc') \
        .mode(mode) \
        .option('user', username) \
        .option('password', password) \
        .option('driver', driver) \
        .option('dbtable', table_name) \
        .option('url', connection_url) \
        .save()


Still, after trying, none of the solutions work, is there any missing part or was there a part that I have misconfigured it?

I have tried different editions of the same ojdbc8.jar, I even go to the older version of Oracle JDCB Driver to download the ojdbc8.jar, hence, none of them work

The error indicates that you (also?) have the ojdbc10 (Oracle JDBC driver for Java 10) driver on the classpath
